# how to set animation on all child of viewflipper

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I have viewflipper for countdown of 5 seconds.

I have applied fading animation but the effect happens only for the first time.

i.e when 5 changes to 4. from thereon no animation takes effect.

```
public class TatSplash extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ViewFlipper timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tatsplash);
    timer = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timer.setOnClickListener(this);
    timer.setFlipInterval(1000);
    timer.startFlipping();

    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    timer.setAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    timer.showNext();

}
}
```

I want the animations for all views.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try...?

```
viewFlipper.setInAnimation();
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation();
```

Comment: yeah working now. i thought only viewFlipper.setAnimation(); is required. thanks !